# Arranging images on top of each other like on the examples

Tags: html, css, image

This is my first time posting so please go easy on me.

So I'm trying to arrange separated images into specific arrangement [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU7RS.png)
And this is my code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3mdrp1n/1/).

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <h1>Arrange this</h1>
        <div class="garuda-container">
            <div><img class="kepala hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/vmxvnPxD/kepala.png"></div>
            <div><img class="leher hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/6qcVKggb/leher.png" alt=""></div>
            <div><img class="sayap hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/RZH3Q2Gr/sayap.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="tameng-container">
                <img class="tameng partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/pdjDrp3F/tameng.png" alt="">
                <img class="banteng hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/52N7XqmF/banteng.png" alt="">
                <img class="beringin hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/cL9DwgDk/beringin.png" alt="">
                <img class="bintang hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/hGNp3FR9/bintang.png" alt="">
                <img class="padikapas hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/3xdjMLB9/padikapas.png" alt="">      
                <img class="rantai hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/LXd33zjD/rantai.png" alt="">
            </div>     
            <div><img class="kaki hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/C5hDcJ5G/kaki.png" alt=""></div>
            <div><img class="semboyan hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/ZKD3L8SN/semboyan.png" alt=""></div>
            <div><img class="ekor hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/fyD76D20/ekor.png" alt=""></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item explainer">
        <h1>Into this</h1>
        <img style="zoom: 50%" src="https://i.postimg.cc/d3hQQTxM/garudapancasila.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: white;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    margin: 0.125rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.garuda-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.partgaruda {
    /* position: absolute; */
    max-width: 100%;
    zoom: 25%;
}

.hoverable:hover {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1.5rem white);
}
```

The reason I make them individual is so when I hover each part of the image it will have drop shadow (shown in jsfiddle). So am I on the right track or is there a better way to do what I want to do? I'm sorry if I'm not clear, I'm still new to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how critical it is for you to use "display: grid", but the traditional implementation (using "position") is simple and straightforward:

```css
.garuda-container {
  position: relative; height: 50em; width: 46.375em;
  /* The scale of the picture. */
  font-size: clamp(1px, calc(90vh / 48), calc(90vw / 48));
}

.garuda-container>img { position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translatex(-50%); }
.garuda-container>img:nth-of-type(1) { top: 34.625em; width: 16.875em; }
.garuda-container>img:nth-of-type(2) { top: 34.875em; width: 41.25em; }
.garuda-container>img:nth-of-type(3) { top: 0em; width: 46.3125em; }
.garuda-container>img:nth-of-type(4) { top: 29.375em; width: 28.375em; }
.garuda-container>img:nth-of-type(5) { top: 10.3125em; left: calc(50% + 0.1em); width: 10.5em; }
.garuda-container>img:nth-of-type(6) { top: 3.8125em; left: calc(50% - 1.2em); width: 11.875em; }

.tameng-container { position: relative; }

.tameng-container>img { position: absolute; }
.tameng-container>img:nth-of-type(1) { top: 17.5625em; right: 50%; width: 7.8125em; }
.tameng-container>img:nth-of-type(2) { top: 17.5625em; left: 50%; width: 7.8125em; }
.tameng-container>img:nth-of-type(3) { top: 26.1875em; right: 50%; width: 7.8125em; }
.tameng-container>img:nth-of-type(4) { top: 26.1875em; left: 50%; width: 7.8125em; }
.tameng-container>img:nth-of-type(5) { top: 17.5625em; left: 50%; width: 15.75em; transform: translatex(-50%); pointer-events: none; }
.tameng-container>img:nth-of-type(6) { top: 23.375em; left: 50%; z-index: 1; width: 5.9375em; transform: translatex(-50%); }

.partgaruda { height: auto; width: 100%; }

.hoverable:hover { filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.25em white) drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em yellow) drop-shadow(0 0 1.5em white); }
/* Additional effect for inactive parts on hover. Optional. */
.garuda-container:hover .partgaruda:not(:hover) { filter: blur(3px); }

body { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; background-color: darkslategrey; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; }
```

```html
<div class="garuda-container">
  <img class="ekor hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/fyD76D20/ekor.png" alt="">
  <img class="semboyan hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/ZKD3L8SN/semboyan.png" alt="">
  <img class="sayap hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/RZH3Q2Gr/sayap.png" alt="">
  <img class="kaki hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/C5hDcJ5G/kaki.png" alt="">
  <img class="leher hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/6qcVKggb/leher.png" alt="">
  <img class="kepala hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/vmxvnPxD/kepala.png" alt="">
  <div class="tameng-container">
    <img class="banteng hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/52N7XqmF/banteng.png" alt="">
    <img class="beringin hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/cL9DwgDk/beringin.png" alt="">
    <img class="padikapas hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/3xdjMLB9/padikapas.png" alt="">
    <img class="rantai hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/LXd33zjD/rantai.png" alt="">
    <img class="tameng partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/pdjDrp3F/tameng.png" alt="">
    <img class="bintang hoverable partgaruda" src="https://i.postimg.cc/hGNp3FR9/bintang.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My god you just blew my mind lol. I don't know how you do it, I'm gonna learn your code tomorrow morning. I want to have a text on the side that's why I use grid so that when I hover over the head for example its gonna show a text on the right side.

Also another question, I noticed that when I hover on the butt its still selecting the leg part. I'm guessing because HTML doesnt ignore transparent part of the image? is there a way to make it work?